# Flutter how to change app icon that generated using very_good cli (Very Good Venture)

Tags: flutter, appicon

I have generated my Flutter app using [very_good_cli](https://pub.dev/packages/very_good_cli).

I'm using [flutter_launcher_icon](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_launcher_icons) to change the default app icon.

I make sure that the old icon does not exist in the project, but still, the `very_good_cli` icon appears after reinstalling the app.

[image]

Where does it get this icon if it does not exist in the project?

**What are the steps I need to take to change the app's icon that was generated by `very_good_cli`?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Updating App Icons for very_good_cli

When you create a new project, it has a default launcher icon. To customize this icon, you can do it by using the following steps for each platform.

### Android

1. Review the Material Design product icons guidelines for icon design.
2. In the [project]/android/app/src/main/res/ directory, place your icon files in folders named using configuration qualifiers. The default mipmap- folders demonstrate the correct naming convention.
3. In AndroidManifest.xml, update the application tag’s android:icon attribute to reference icons from the previous step (for example, <application android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher" ...).
4. To verify that the icon has been replaced, run your app and inspect the app icon in the Launcher.

### iOS

1. Review the iOS App Icon guidelines.
2. In the Xcode project navigator, select Assets.xcassets in the Runner folder. Update the placeholder icons with your own app icons.
3. Verify the icon has been replaced by running your app using flutter run.

https://github.com/VeryGoodOpenSource/very_good_cli/blob/main/doc/very_good_core.md#updating-app-icons-

Comment: The link you shared is no longer valid. You might want to update it if you know where the new documentation is located.